# Fail to install cairo haskell bindings on windows

Tags: haskell, cabal, cairo

I am trying to install cairo-0.12.4 Haskell package on Windows 7. I first downloaded and unpacked Gtk+2 and added its bin subdir to PATH. I then tried to run cabal with extra libs and includes:

```
cabal --extra-lib-dirs="d:\Program Files (x86)\Gtk+\lib" 
      --extra-include-dirs="d:\Program Files (x86)\Gtk+\include" install
```

But I got the following error

```
 Reading available packages...
 Choosing modular solver.
 Resolving dependencies...
 Ready to install cairo-0.12.4
 Waiting for install task to finish...
 Extracting
 C:\Users\abailly\AppData\Roaming\cabal\packages\hackage.haskell.org\cairo\0.12.4\cairo-0.12.4.tar.gz
 to C:\Users\abailly\AppData\Local\Temp\cairo-0.12.4-2368...
 Updating cairo.cabal with the latest revision from the index.
 creating
 C:\Users\abailly\AppData\Local\Temp\cairo-0.12.4-2368\cairo-0.12.4\dist\setup
 creating
 C:\Users\abailly\AppData\Local\Temp\cairo-0.12.4-2368\cairo-0.12.4\dist
 creating
 C:\Users\abailly\AppData\Local\Temp\cairo-0.12.4-2368\cairo-0.12.4\dist\setup
 d:\Program Files (x86)\Haskell Platform\2012.2.0.0\bin\ghc.exe --make C:\Users\abailly\AppData\Local\Temp\cairo-0.12.4-2368\cairo-
 0.12.4\Setup.hs -o C:\Users\abailly\AppData\Local\Temp\cairo-0.12.4-2368\cairo-0.12.4\dist\setup\setup.exe -odir C:\Users\abailly\
 AppData\Local\Temp\cairo-0.12.4-2368\cairo-0.12.4\dist\setup -hidir C:\Users\abailly\AppData\Local\Temp\cairo-0.12.4-2368\cairo-0.
 12.4\dist\setup -i -iC:\Users\abailly\AppData\Local\Temp\cairo-0.12.4-2368\cairo-0.12.4 -package Cabal-1.14.0
 [1 of 2] Compiling SetupWrapper     ( C:\Users\abailly\AppData\Local\Temp\cairo-0.12.4-2368\cairo-0.12.4\SetupWrapper.hs, C:\Users
 \abailly\AppData\Local\Temp\cairo-0.12.4-2368\cairo-0.12.4\dist\setup\SetupWrapper.o )
 [2 of 2] Compiling Main             ( C:\Users\abailly\AppData\Local\Temp\cairo-0.12.4-2368\cairo-0.12.4\Setup.hs, C:\Users\abaill
 y\AppData\Local\Temp\cairo-0.12.4-2368\cairo-0.12.4\dist\setup\Main.o )
 Linking C:\Users\abailly\AppData\Local\Temp\cairo-0.12.4-2368\cairo-0.12.4\dist\setup\setup.exe ...
 C:\Users\abailly\AppData\Local\Temp\cairo-0.12.4-2368\cairo-0.12.4\dist\setup\setup.exe
 configure --verbose=2 --ghc --prefix=C:\Users\abailly\AppData\Roaming\cabal
 --user --flags=cairo_svg --flags=cairo_ps --flags=cairo_pdf
 --extra-include-dirs=D:\Program Files (x86)\Gtk+\include
 --extra-lib-dirs=D:\Program Files (x86)\Gtk+\lib --constraint=mtl ==2.1.2
 --constraint=bytestring ==0.9.2.1 --constraint=base ==4.5.0.0
 --constraint=array ==0.4.0.0 --disable-tests --disable-benchmarks
 [1 of 2] Compiling Gtk2HsSetup      ( Gtk2HsSetup.hs, dist\setup-wrapper\Gtk2HsSetup.o )
 [2 of 2] Compiling Main             ( SetupMain.hs, dist\setup-wrapper\Main.o )
 Linking dist/setup-wrapper\setup.exe ...
 Configuring cairo-0.12.4...
 Flags chosen: cairo_svg=True, cairo_ps=True, cairo_pdf=True
 Dependency array ==0.4.0.0: using array-0.4.0.0
 Dependency base ==4.5.0.0: using base-4.5.0.0
 Dependency bytestring ==0.9.2.1: using bytestring-0.9.2.1
 Dependency mtl ==2.1.2: using mtl-2.1.2
 Dependency cairo-pdf -any: using version 1.10.2
 Dependency cairo-ps -any: using version 1.10.2
 Dependency cairo-svg -any: using version 1.10.2
 Dependency cairo >=1.2.0: using version 1.10.2
 Using Cabal-1.14.0 compiled by ghc-7.4
 Using compiler: ghc-7.4.1
 Using install prefix: C:\Users\abailly\AppData\Roaming\cabal
 Binaries installed in: C:\Users\abailly\AppData\Roaming\cabal\bin
 Libraries installed in:
 C:\Users\abailly\AppData\Roaming\cabal\cairo-0.12.4\ghc-7.4.1
 Private binaries installed in:
 C:\Users\abailly\AppData\Roaming\cabal\cairo-0.12.4
 Data files installed in: C:\Users\abailly\AppData\Roaming\cabal\cairo-0.12.4
 Documentation installed in:
 C:\Users\abailly\AppData\Roaming\cabal\doc\cairo-0.12.4
 Using alex version 3.0.1 found on system at: d:\Program Files (x86)\Haskell
 Platform\2012.2.0.0\lib\extralibs\bin\alex.exe
 Using ar found on system at: d:\Program Files (x86)\Haskell
 Platform\2012.2.0.0\mingw\bin\ar.exe
 No c2hs found
 Using cpphs version 1.16 found on system at:
 c:\Users\abailly\AppData\Roaming\cabal\bin\cpphs.exe
 No ffihugs found
 Using gcc version 4.5.2 found on system at: d:\Program Files (x86)\Haskell
 Platform\2012.2.0.0\mingw\bin\gcc.exe
 Using ghc version 7.4.1 found on system at: d:\Program Files (x86)\Haskell
 Platform\2012.2.0.0\bin\ghc.exe
 Using ghc-pkg version 7.4.1 found on system at: d:\Program Files (x86)\Haskell
 Platform\2012.2.0.0\bin\ghc-pkg.exe
 No greencard found
 Using gtk2hsC2hs version 0.13.6 found on system at:
 c:\Users\abailly\AppData\Roaming\cabal\bin\gtk2hsC2hs.exe
 Using gtk2hsHookGenerator found on system at:
 c:\Users\abailly\AppData\Roaming\cabal\bin\gtk2hsHookGenerator.exe
 Using gtk2hsTypeGen found on system at:
 c:\Users\abailly\AppData\Roaming\cabal\bin\gtk2hsTypeGen.exe
 Using haddock version 2.10.0 found on system at: d:\Program Files
 (x86)\Haskell Platform\2012.2.0.0\bin\haddock.exe
 Using happy version 1.18.9 found on system at: d:\Program Files (x86)\Haskell
 Platform\2012.2.0.0\lib\extralibs\bin\happy.exe
 No hmake found
 Using hpc version 0.6 found on system at: d:\Program Files (x86)\Haskell
 Platform\2012.2.0.0\bin\hpc.exe
 Using hsc2hs version 0.67 found on system at: d:\Program Files (x86)\Haskell
 Platform\2012.2.0.0\bin\hsc2hs.exe
 Using hscolour version 1.20 found on system at:
 c:\Users\abailly\AppData\Roaming\cabal\bin\HsColour.exe
 No hugs found
 No jhc found
 Using ld found on system at: d:\Program Files (x86)\Haskell
 Platform\2012.2.0.0\mingw\bin\ld.exe
 No lhc found
 No lhc-pkg found
 No nhc98 found
 Using pkg-config version 0.26 found on system at: d:\Program Files
 (x86)\Gtk+\bin\pkg-config.exe
 Using ranlib found on system at: d:\Program Files (x86)\Haskell
 Platform\2012.2.0.0\mingw\bin\ranlib.exe
 Using strip found on system at: d:\Program Files (x86)\Haskell
 Platform\2012.2.0.0\mingw\bin\strip.exe
 Using tar found on system at: D:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\tar.exe
 No uhc found
 d:\Program Files (x86)\Gtk+\bin\pkg-config.exe --modversion cairo-pdf
 d:\Program Files (x86)\Gtk+\bin\pkg-config.exe --modversion cairo-ps
 d:\Program Files (x86)\Gtk+\bin\pkg-config.exe --modversion cairo-svg
 d:\Program Files (x86)\Gtk+\bin\pkg-config.exe --modversion cairo
 setup.exe: Missing dependencies on foreign libraries:
 * Missing C libraries: z, cairo
 This problem can usually be solved by installing the system packages that
 provide these libraries (you may need the "-dev" versions). If the libraries
 are already installed but in a non-standard location then you can use the
 flags --extra-include-dirs= and --extra-lib-dirs= to specify where they are.
 Failed to install cairo-0.12.4
 cabal.exe: Error: some packages failed to install:
 Chart-0.16 depends on cairo-0.12.4 which failed to install.
 cairo-0.12.4 failed during the configure step. The exception was:
 ExitFailure 1
 splot-0.3.8 depends on cairo-0.12.4 which failed to install.
```

When I try to install cairo directly, I got the following:

```
d:\Program Files (x86)\Gtk+\bin\pkg-config.exe --modversion cairo-pdf
d:\Program Files (x86)\Gtk+\bin\pkg-config.exe --modversion cairo-ps
d:\Program Files (x86)\Gtk+\bin\pkg-config.exe --modversion cairo-svg
d:\Program Files (x86)\Gtk+\bin\pkg-config.exe --modversion cairo
setup.exe: Missing dependencies on foreign libraries:
* Missing C libraries: z, cairo
This problem can usually be solved by installing the system packages that
provide these libraries (you may need the "-dev" versions). If the libraries
are already installed but in a non-standard location then you can use the
flags --extra-include-dirs= and --extra-lib-dirs= to specify where they are.
Failed to install cairo-0.12.4
World file is already up to date.
cabal.exe: Error: some packages failed to install:
cairo-0.12.4 failed during the configure step. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
```

I am clueless...

Answer (score 4):

If you read the error message:

```
* Missing C libraries: z, cairo
```

It is saying you need to install the libraries (and header files) for the libraries libz and cairo.  On *nix systems this usually means just installing the `-dev` versions of these packages with your package manager.  On windows I assume you'd download the source version of the library and install.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As I said, I downloaded the gitk+ bundle which contains both DLLs and headers. AFAICT, those libraries are present on my system in the D:\Program Files (x86)\Gtk+\ directory: 
 - z -> include\zlib.h
 - cairo -> include\cairo\cairo.h
 - cairo.lib -> lib\
 - zdll.lib -> lib\

I tweaked cabal command-line to add the DLLs and include paths to cabal. Hence my puzzlement...

Comment: BTW I had a look to building cairo from source on windows but I did not (yet) try this as I expected the pre-built binary bundles to be more than enough given my needs. I maybe wrong, of course.

Comment: Whatever the intent of the GTK library you downloaded, the situation seems to be that your (cabal) build does not know where to find cairo or z.  It might take some fiddling to figure out why not.

Comment: I understand. But I was expecting some "fiddling directions" from people more knowledgeable than me :-) Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2):

I got this problem. In my case it was a mismatch between a 64-bit ghc and a 32-bit cairo dll

Answer (score 1):

I moved the Gtk+ library to `D:\soft\gtk+\` and everything runs fine. The path to Gtk+ contain space which does not seem to be correctly interpreted by cabal/ghc, although I double-quoted it:

```
--extra-lib-dirs="d:\Program Files (x86)\Gtk+\lib"
```

*Solution*: Put gtk+ in a space-free location.

**Update**: Now, it fails to install Chart-0.16 with an even more cryptic error:

```
Loading package Win32-2.2.2.0 ... linking ... done.
Loading package array-0.4.0.0 ... linking ... done.
Loading package deepseq-1.3.0.0 ... linking ... done.
Loading package old-locale-1.0.0.4 ... linking ... done.
Loading package time-1.4 ... linking ... done.
Loading package containers-0.4.2.1 ... linking ... done.
Loading package transformers-0.3.0.0 ... linking ... done.
Loading package data-accessor-0.2.2.3 ... linking ... done.
Loading package pretty-1.1.1.0 ... linking ... done.
Loading package template-haskell ... linking ... done.
Loading package utility-ht-0.0.8 ... linking ... done.
Loading package data-accessor-template-0.2.1.10 ... linking ... done.
Loading package colour-2.3.3 ... linking ... done.
Loading package mtl-2.1.2 ... linking ... done.
*** gcc:
"D:\Program Files (x86)\Haskell Platform\2012.2.0.0\lib/../mingw/bin/gcc.exe" "-fno-stack-protector" "-Wl,--hash-size=31" "-Wl,--r
educe-memory-overheads" "-LC:\Users\abailly\AppData\Roaming\cabal\cairo-0.12.4\ghc-7.4.1" "-Ld:/soft/Gtk+/lib" "--print-file-name"
 "libz.dll"
*** gcc:
"D:\Program Files (x86)\Haskell Platform\2012.2.0.0\lib/../mingw/bin/gcc.exe" "-fno-stack-protector" "-Wl,--hash-size=31" "-Wl,--r
educe-memory-overheads" "-LC:\Users\abailly\AppData\Roaming\cabal\cairo-0.12.4\ghc-7.4.1" "-Ld:/soft/Gtk+/lib" "--print-file-name"
 "libcairo-2.dll"
Loading package cairo-0.12.4 ... d:\Program Files (x86)\Haskell Platform\2012.2.0.0\bin\ghc.exe returned
ExitFailure 1
Failed to install Chart-0.16
cabal.exe: Error: some packages failed to install:
Chart-0.16 failed during the building phase. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
splot-0.3.8 depends on Chart-0.16 which failed to install.
```

I suspect this is due to a linking error as the compilation runs fine when I execute the following command which is what cabal outputs in debug mode:

```
 "D:\\Program Files (x86)\\Haskell Platform\\2012.2.0.0\\bin\\ghc.exe"
 "--make" "-v" "-fbuilding-cabal-package" "-O" "-odir" "dist\\build"
 "-hidir" "dist\\build" "-stubdir" "dist\\build" "-i" "-idist\\build"
 "-i." "-idist\\build\\autogen" "-Idist\\build\\autogen"
 "-Idist\\build" "-optP-include"
 "-optPdist\\build\\autogen\\cabal_macros.h" "-package-name"
 "Chart-0.16" "-hide-all-packages" "-package-conf"
 "dist\\package.conf.inplace" "-package-id"
 "array-0.4.0.0-3cf1bc3f5cd0078adea24752c18081b9" "-package-id"
 "base-4.5.0.0-597748f6f53a7442bcae283373264bb6" "-package-id"
 "cairo-0.12.4-f04021ea456c901e8d05395a31f7a861" "-package-id"
 "colour-2.3.3-4eaa610bb6d825a7334e1b3de448f6c0" "-package-id"
 "data-accessor-0.2.2.3-5477c48e3478339fdff299c536a033c6" "-package-id"
 "data-accessor-template-0.2.1.10-28ee96821fd908880f3a49417c4da548"
 "-package-id" "mtl-2.1.2-7ec8bbada2af74b49c6e4aeea2889fdc"
 "-package-id" "old-locale-1.0.0.4-29bd50ed2bb4a20928338f52e4ab1b71"
 "-package-id" "time-1.4-01d7bf22d87e70510fe9ee4c4434b3ab"
 "-XHaskell98" "Graphics.Rendering.Chart"
 "Graphics.Rendering.Chart.Types" "Graphics.Rendering.Chart.Renderable"
 "Graphics.Rendering.Chart.Axis"
 "Graphics.Rendering.Chart.Axis.Floating"
 "Graphics.Rendering.Chart.Axis.Indexed"
 "Graphics.Rendering.Chart.Axis.Int"
 "Graphics.Rendering.Chart.Axis.LocalTime"
 "Graphics.Rendering.Chart.Axis.Types"
 "Graphics.Rendering.Chart.Axis.Unit" "Graphics.Rendering.Chart.Layout"
 "Graphics.Rendering.Chart.Legend" "Graphics.Rendering.Chart.Simple"
 "Graphics.Rendering.Chart.Simple.Internal"
 "Graphics.Rendering.Chart.Grid" "Graphics.Rendering.Chart.Plot"
 "Graphics.Rendering.Chart.Plot.Types"
 "Graphics.Rendering.Chart.Plot.Annotation"
 "Graphics.Rendering.Chart.Plot.AreaSpots"
 "Graphics.Rendering.Chart.Plot.Bars"
 "Graphics.Rendering.Chart.Plot.Candle"
 "Graphics.Rendering.Chart.Plot.ErrBars"
 "Graphics.Rendering.Chart.Plot.FillBetween"
 "Graphics.Rendering.Chart.Plot.Hidden"
 "Graphics.Rendering.Chart.Plot.Lines"
 "Graphics.Rendering.Chart.Plot.Pie"
 "Graphics.Rendering.Chart.Plot.Points"
 "Graphics.Rendering.Chart.SparkLine" "-hide-package" "monads-tf"
```

I am even more puzzled...

**Update (2)**: When I run `cabal install > out 2>&1` it succeeds!